# Android Studio/XML Special characters encoding

Tags: android, xml, character-encoding, special-characters

I am working in the layout files with XML and I have a TextView that must contain several special characters like "‡", "oe", "ƒ"... (even my browser failed to display them correctly, so I don't know if you got them right)

**how can I write those characters in XML ??**

**will they be displayed correctly in android devices ??**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save them in xml using html-code but, this is mostly not needed if they are in the UTF-8 notation, actual characters will also do:

```
<string name="my_string">&#65;</string>
```

Or, you can call `setText()` with unicode on the `TextView`:

```
textView.setText("\u266b");
```

If you need, you can reference this [unicode table](http://unicode-table.com/en/).

Comment: if you don't mind answering this : which form is the correct one : textView.setText("\U+01EB"); or textView.setText("\u01eb");

Answer (score 0):

Use xml to keep these unicode strings:

> Note: you <strike>don't have to use all languages</strike> below, if you only need one of them, it is perfectly fine.

Default (English), res/values/strings.xml, for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="title">Maps</string>
    <string name="open_in">Open in Google Maps</string>
</resources>
```

French, res/values-fr/strings.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="title">Plans</string>
    <string name="open_in">Ouvrir dans Google Maps</string>
</resources>
```

Japanese, res/values-ja/strings.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="title">マップ</string>
    <string name="open_in">Googleマップで開く</string>
</resources>
```

To use the string in these xml files:

```
yourTextView.setText(R.string.title);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can use html code with special characters, this is the page I used to search for special html code list:
https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref

Bonus: if you want to setText to a text view with special characters from Java code, you can use this:

```
 Html.fromHtml("//html code here")
```

Answer (score 0):

this will do the job 
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("your special character text"));